# Wamp and xml_unserializer issue

Tags: php, wamp, pear

I am trying to fix an online site, but before that I would like to make it work on my local machine/wamp. Everytime I click on Search event and Register links on the site, the error below shows up.

```
Warning: require_once(XML/Unserializer.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\xxxxxx\includes\common_form_controls.php on line 19

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'XML/Unserializer.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\itsonat\includes\common_form_controls.php on line 19
```

Is it because I don't have xml_unserializer installed on my computer? Where and How do I install it? I've been trying to install Pear in my wamp, but I am unsure of the relationship between Pear and XML_serializer.

Can someone please help me on how to fix this problem?

Thanks heaps. S:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEAR can be installed, of course. There are a [couple](http://phphints.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/installing-pear-package-manager-on-wamp/) of [guides](http://crc-stc.com/How_to_Install_PHP_PEAR_on_WampServer) out there.

Also, install the PEAR modules required by your app to work properly, perhaps following this [guide](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/xml-php-pear-xml_serializer/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, I will give it a try. Thank you very much. S:)